# LINQ to SQL and field concatenation in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to create a LINQ query which results in the following SQL statement. Let's say I have a simple table with just two character fields - field1 and field2. My SQL statement would be:

```
    SELECT field1, field2, field1+field2 AS ConcatField
    FROM TableX
    WHERE field1+field2 = 'abcdef'
```

How can this be done in LINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `let` clause for defining your concatfield and then select an anonymous type with the 3 fields you want to return.

```
from f in TableX
let concatfield = f.Field1 + f.Field2
where concatfield = 'abcdef'
select new
{
  f.Field1,
  f.Field2,
  concatfield
}
```

Regarding to your example of the more complex where clause,you would need to build an array of the values you want to compare to and then do something like this:

```
  List<string> values = .....

  from f in TableX
  let concatfield = f.Field1 + f.Field2
  where values.Contains(concatfield)
  select new
  {
     f.Field1,
     f.Field2,
     concatfield
  }
```

Comment: This is perfect. Now let's make it a little more complicated:    
`SELECT field1, field2, field1+field2 AS ConcatField
    FROM TableX
    WHERE field1+field2 IN ('abcdef', 'hijklm')`

Comment: If you have only 2 elements, I'd suggest just to duplicate the clause. If you have a lot, and what the where to be done server-side, you have to upload the elements into a table, then join on that table.

Comment: Thank you very much, this definetely brings me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Using LinqToSql this can be acomplished by projecting into an anonymous type and a field in it which is a combination of the two fileds that you've mentioned:

```
var  concatenatedField = from c in ConcatFields
                             where c.something == somethignElse
                             select new {
                               field1 = c.field1
                               field2 = c.field2
                               field3 = c.field1 + c.field2
                              }
```